# не переходит в директорию

Tags: cmd

необходимо перейти в директорию на диске D.
Но я всё равно остаюсь в диске C.
[image: cmd]

Comment: cmd или всё-таки sh?

Comment: cmd, просто у меня аналог его (conEmu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте сменить диск набрав "D:"

Answer (score 5):

Команда CD (CHDIR) имеет опциональный ключ `/D`, который переключает и диск.

Без этого ключа текущий каталог для указанного диска - изменяется, но сам текущий диск остаётся прежним.

Т.е. либо

```
cd /d x:\folder
```

либо

```
x:
cd \folder
```

В последнем случае порядок команд неважен.
Можно последний случай собрать и в одну команду:

```
x: && cd \folder
```